# Java performance of redesigning nested loops into methods

Tags: java, performance, nested-loops

Someone asked me about this and after reading some big O stuff I still can't figure out which of the 2 designs is faster.

If I have this kind of nested loop in one method

```
public void someMethod(){
    for (a=0;a<10;a++){
     for (b=0;b<10;b++){
      for (c=0;c<10;c++){
       for (d=0;d<10;d++){
       }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

and I decided to redesign the method and place the 2 inner for loops to another method something like this

```
public void someMethod(){
     for (a=0;a<10;a++){
         for (b=0;b<10;b++){
          2loopsMethod();
         }
        }
    }

public void 2loopsMethod(){
for (c=0;c<10;c++){
 for (d=0;d<10;d++){
 }
}
```

}

My question is will the redesigned method  be alot faster that the original code since I placed it in another method or will it make no difference?

Comment: Why do you think that could help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should make no difference.  You still have four levels of nested loops, so delegating part of the work to a method call will not be faster.

(Technically the added overhead of the method call will make the second example *slightly* slower, but if your code is doing anything significant at all I'd be surprised if you can even measure the difference.)

Comment: I see thanks for answering still have lot to learn about java. Do you know have some links where I can easily this kind of stuff? Or Its just learning by experience?

Comment: @dimas Experience is the best teacher, but there's still a lot to be learned from books, tutorials, and asking questions like this one.  For Java specifically, the official [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are an extremely good resource, as are the Java tutorial videos on http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php

Comment: thanks for the links especially the videos, I learn a lot faster if I watch people do it.

Answer (score 1):

Big O complexity is the same. I think the first version is faster because you don't have the a*b method calls. And in theory method calls take extra time.

Answer (score 1):

The redesigned method is a just a little little bit slower in your case because method invocation takes additional time (unlikely e.g. to C++ inline functions). You'll definitely see the difference if you increase the number of loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Due to compiler optimizations on methods, second example is preffered:

```html
public class Try1 {

 static int sum;
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  long startTime, endTime;

  while(true)
  {
   sum = 0;
   startTime = System.nanoTime();
   for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
     sum = sum + i;
    }
   }
   
   endTime = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("no method took:" + (endTime -startTime) );

   sum = 0;
   startTime = System.nanoTime();
   for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { 
    func(i);
   }
   endTime = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("with method took:" + (endTime -startTime) );
   
  }

 }

 private static final void func(int i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
   sum = sum + i;
  }
 }

}
```

end the results:

no method took:3077459
with method took:2418027
no method took:5535578
with method took:76014
no method took:3857167
with method took:88844
no method took:3758701
with method took:89165
no method took:3761588
with method took:88844